# exec() does not work all commands i send

Tags: php, linux

I am making a website for a device so that the user can change the primary and secondary IP that it connects to. I am using 'exec()' to get the IP's for me. i made a function for that called 'File_read' that work great. the problem I am having is with saving it back to the same file. i still use 'exec()', the function is called 'file_write'. Below is my code for the two

```
function file_read()
{
$arr_out = "";
$arr_test_1 = "";
$arr_test_2 = "";

exec(@'cat /usr/triton/config/protman.conf | grep "Primary ="',$arr_test_1);
exec(@'cat /usr/triton/config/protman.conf | grep "Secondary ="',$arr_test_2);
$arr_out[0] = IP_edit(end($arr_test_1));
$arr_out[1] = IP_edit(end($arr_test_2));

$arr_out[2] = end($arr_test_1);
$arr_out[3] = end($arr_test_2);

return $arr_out;
}

function file_write($arr_in)
{
$save_1 = "";
$save_2 = "";
$build_1 = "";
$build_2 = "";

$build_1 = 'Primary = "'.$arr_in[0].'";';
$build_2 = 'Secondary = "'.$arr_in[1].'";';

$save_1 = @"sed -i 's/".$arr_in[2]."/".$build_1."/' /usr/triton/config/protman.conf";
$save_2 = @"sed -i 's/".$arr_in[3]."/".$build_2."/' /usr/triton/config/protman.conf";

echo "<br/>test save 1 = ".$save_1;
echo "<br/>test save 2 = ".$save_2;

exec($save_1);
exec($save_2);

}
```

i tested the string it builds to write to the file but and it is as follows.

```
sed -i 's/Primary = "10.200.26.144";/Primary = "10.98.227.30";/' /usr/triton/config/protman.conf
```

This is for '$save_1'. When i use it on putty it works so why does it not work with 'exec()'? am i missing something or is their a easier way to do this?

Comment: Did you check your webserver logs to see what error message you might be getting? My guess is it's permissions and the webserver / php doesn't have rights to modify the file.

Comment: Yes it does have the right i believe. i can open the  file with 'foepn($file_name,w)' and after that i made the file so that everyone can change it. but i will try adding the '$out'

Answer (score 0):

has `PHP` the rights to execute this command and access to this file ?

Also, you could try giving a second argument `$out` (as array) to the `exec` function to handle details/info

Comment: Yes it does have the right i believe. i can open the  file with 'foepn($file_name,w)' and after that i made the file so that everyone can change it.

Comment: Tried that but it did not change the file does not update. i also added a variable to to the 'exec()' to return the check it does and it returned a 1. Unless i am wrong that means that the function worked.

Comment: No 1 means error. Try using fonction escapeshellcmd() maybe... It May be related to characters escape

Comment: It did not work i changed the 'exec($save)' to '    escapeshellcmd($save_1) or die('<br/>no working 1');' and it does not die.. but it still does not change the file.

Comment: i set the file share code to 7777 that is  to give access to all and still nothing.

Comment: I still cant get it work. Is there another way of editing a file but only changing on line in the text file and not rewriting the hole file.